# Why xcode variables view gives different values for double?

Tags: swift, xcode, variables, double

[image]

When I debugging my app, I got a variables view above. The value which type is `Double` of `planItem.amounts[weekday]` has different values in the view.

When I expand the `amounts`, type is `[Weekday: Double]`, and found the value of key `wednesday`, the view shows me `4.3312800240032489E-311` which is a quite small number, while I added the expression `planItem.amounts[weekday]` where `weekday` is `wednesday`, it shows `10` which is the value I set.

Why Xcode gives me different values for the same variable? 
The version of Xcode I am using is `Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)`.

---

This is not a question about the precision of double stored in computer.

In that case, the numbers should be very close like `0.1` and  `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`.

But in my question, the xcode debugger gives me totally different values of the same variable. They are `10` and `4.3312800240032489E-311` which are definitely totally different number.

I want to know why xcode present a double in dictionary so wrong instead of why floating point decimals stored in computer as binary lose its precision.

Comment: In this case it isn't that floating point math is broken, but rather Xcode's debugger is broken

Comment: This is not a duplicated question. I added explanation in my question. This is not about the precision but the reason of two totally different presentation in xcode debugger. @Alexander